# how send data saved in local xml file to server? objectivec

Tags: iphone, xml, web-services

I have an project in which i retrieve data from user and save in local xml file. I have done all this on simulator. Now i want to deploy on iPhone device. But problem is that how send file (XML) from iphone to server by using web services?

Comment: Can you please explain what webservice you use? Or do you have to write it yourself?

Comment: No i don't write anything. Can u tell me how do that? Idon't have any idea.

Comment: It's an other programming language. I use PHP to write webservices. Because in my opinion it's very similar to Objective-c. ;-)

Comment: So u please tell me what ever u use web service.

Comment: I can't share them with you because they are private and do just straightforward task like a password restore... ;-)

Comment: why not u tell me only structure of that/

Comment: @SandroMeier let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/1616/discussion-between-ram-and-sandro-meier)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can HTTP POST it:

```
NSString * xmlString = @"<test><message length="5">Hello</message></test>";

NSURL * serviceUrl = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://my.company.com/myservice"];
NSMutableURLRequest * serviceRequest = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:serviceUrl];
[serviceRequest setValue:@"text/xml" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-type"];
[serviceRequest setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
[serviceRequest setHTTPBody:[xmlString dataUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding]];

NSURLResponse * serviceResponse;
NSError * serviceError;
serviceResponse = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:serviceRequest       returningResponse:&serviceResponse error:&serviceError];
```

Taken from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1130969/how-send-file-txt-xml-from-iphone-to-serverweb-or-email)

Comment: We need more information about your Webservice. Else we can't help you. ;-)

Comment: As you can see above, you have an XML string and a web service, then you send a request to the web service and get a response. Pretty straightforward.

Comment: i have xml file so how i rplace XML string by XML file.